# Notification not being shown on Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm building a simple application whose purpose is to show a notification as soon as the app is launched.

Following the steps described by the Android's documentation, I wrote a method named `createNotification`, which sets up the notification, and inserted a call to that method into `onCreate` method, which is called few moments after the application is launched, I suppose.

Nevertheless, no notification shows up when the application is launched. I'm wondering what is wrong with the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    // ...

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...

        createNotification();
    }

    private void createNotification() {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC); 

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = 
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(1, builder.build());

    }

}
```

Comment: check API level  `NotificationCompat.Builder` can use only in Android 4.1 and higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification)

> **Required notification contents**
>
> A Notification object *must* contain the following:
>
> - A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()
> - A title, set by setContentTitle()
> - Detail text, set by setContentText()

If you add a smallIcon, for example `android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert` it will work (I tested this just now). You can of course also add an icon of your own, but I used this because it is a builtin so easy for examples.

So like this

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert) // Add this line
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
```

I must say that I find it weird it doesn't show an error or anything when you don't add a smallIcon.

Comment: It worked after an icon was set. No error indeed was pointed out by eclipse and Android-related log.